# How chould i get title where "Title characters contains input box then get the values"

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, client-object-model

i am trying to get the title if it contains the characters in an input box
So first if the user types ABC, then get the titles that contains A,B or C

```
 $("#subSiteTitle").keypress(function () {
    var checkTextTypedIn = $('#subSiteTitle').val();

            hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
            appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
            var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
            function execCrossDomainRequest() {
                var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
                var queryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webs?$select=Title,Url,WebTemplate&$filter=WebTemplate ne 'APP'&$where=Title.Contains=checkTextTypedIn&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

                executor.executeAsync(
                     {
                         url: queryUrl,
                         method: "GET",
                         headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                         success: successHandler,
                         error: errorHandler
                     }
                         );
            }
});
```

This is my input box `var checkTextTypedIn = $('#subSiteTitle').val();`

Here is am trying to se if title contains `$where=Title.Contains=checkTextTypedIn`
its not working right now because i dont now how to write the where statement?
Can someone maybe help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a contains operator available in REST `filter` options.

You can use the `substring` instead

```
var queryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webs?$select=Title,Url,WebTemplate&$filter=WebTemplate ne 'APP' and substringof('" +checkTextTypedIn+"',Title)&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
```

The above query will return all `Web` where `Title` contains `checkTextTypedIn`

Comment: hmm its not working i have writen Sub in my input box because i have 2 subsites names Asub and Sub but i get Could not complete cross-domain call: Bad Request

Comment: @Martin I have updated the query url. Please try that

Comment: It still not working get same error.

Comment: I did just found out that u cant use substring i should use substringof but then it dont display anything will debugg now to se what it says